# Possible infinite recursion when copying keymap

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, doom

When trying to open `vterm`, I get `helm-M-x-execute-command: Possible infinite recursion when copying keymap`. I am using Doom Emacs.

---

`config.el`: https://paste.ofcode.org/Zypm6xQgbXneyJ7LnQvyPK

`+bindings.el`: https://paste.ofcode.org/PdNmSbBrB8GMLYPCVD82G6

After `toggle-debug-on-error`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Possible infinite recursion when copying keymap")
  copy-keymap((keymap (59 . doom/describe-active-minor-mode) (68 . doom/open-manual) (65 . apropos-documentation) (12 . describe-language-environment) (11 . describe-key-briefly) (87 . +default/man-or-woman) (86 . doom/version) (84 . doom/toggle-profiler) (79 . +lookup/online) (77 . doom/describe-active-minor-mode) (69 . doom/open-vanilla-sandbox) (117 . doom/help-autodefs) (39 . doom/what-face) (113 . help-quit) (118 . describe-variable) (119 . +default/man-or-woman) (116 . load-theme) (115 . doom/describe-setters) (82 . doom/reload) (114 . doom/reload-theme) (80 . find-library) (112 . doom/toggle-profiler) (110 . doom/help-news) (111 . describe-symbol) (109 . describe-mode) (108 . find-library) (107 . describe-key) (52 keymap (105 . info-other-window)) (105 . info-lookup-symbol) (104 . #1) (103 . describe-gnu-project) (102 . describe-function) (101 . view-echo-area-messages) (100 keymap (77 . doom/describe-active-minor-mode) (107 . describe-key) (70 . describe-face) (80 . doom/describe-module) (120 . doom/sandbox) (118 . describe-variable) (117 . doom/help-autodefs) (116 . doom/toggle-profiler) (83 . doom/help-search) (115 . doom/help-search-headings) (112 keymap (112 . doom/help-packages) (104 . doom/help-package-homepage) (100 . doom/goto-private-packages-file) (99 . doom/help-package-config)) (78 . doom/help-search-news) (110 . doom/help-news) (109 . describe-mode) (76 . doom/help-search-loaded-files) (108 . doom/help-search-load-path) (104 . doom/help) (102 . describe-function) (100 . doom-debug-mode) (67 . doom/goto-private-init-file) (99 . helpful-at-point) (98 . doom/report-bug)) (99 . describe-char) (98 . doom/open-bug-report) (97 . apropos) (83 . info-lookup-symbol) (76 . global-command-log-mode) (75 . +lookup/documentation) (73 . describe-input-method) (70 . describe-face) (67 . describe-coding-system) (28 . describe-input-method) (23 . describe-no-warranty) (20 . view-emacs-todo) (19 . search-forward-help-for-help) (16 . view-emacs-problems) (15 . describe-distribution) ...))
  byte-code("\301\10!\302\303\304\3#\210\302\305\306\3#\210\302\307\310\3#\210\302\311\312\3#\210\302\313\314\3#\210\302\315\316\3#\210\302\317\320\3#\210\302\321\322\3#..." [help-map copy-keymap substitute-key-definition apropos electric-apropos command-apropos electric-command-apropos describe-key electric-describe-key describe-mode electric-describe-mode view-lossage electric-view-lossage describe-function electric-describe-function describe-variable electric-describe-variable describe-bindings electric-describe-bindings describe-syntax electric-describe-syntax] 5)
  (defvar ehelp-map (byte-code "\301\10!\302\303\304\3#\210\302\305\306\3#\210\302\307\310\3#\210\302\311\312\3#\210\302\313\314\3#\210\302\315\316\3#\210\302\317\320\3#\210\302\321\322\3#..." [help-map copy-keymap substitute-key-definition apropos electric-apropos command-apropos electric-command-apropos describe-key electric-describe-key describe-mode electric-describe-mode view-lossage electric-view-lossage describe-function electric-describe-function describe-variable electric-describe-variable describe-bindings electric-describe-bindings describe-syntax electric-describe-syntax] 5))
  require(ehelp)
  byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\210\300\303!\210\300\304!\210\305\306\307\310\311\312%\207" [require comint ehelp ring shell custom-declare-group term nil "General command interpreter in a window." :group processes] 6)
  require(term)
  byte-code("\301\302\303\304#\204 \0\10\204\22\0\305\306!\203\34\0\307 \210\301\302!\210\202 \0\310\311!\210\301\312!\210\301\313!\210\301\314!\210\301\315!\210\301\316..." [vterm-always-compile-module require vterm-module nil t y-or-n-p "Vterm needs `vterm-module' to work.  Compile it no..." vterm-module-compile error "Vterm will not work until `vterm-module' is compil..." subr-x find-func cl-lib term color compile face-remap custom-declare-variable vterm-shell funcall function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1fdebe18451c9>) "The shell that gets run in the vterm." :type string :group vterm vterm-max-scrollback #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f400015f3f9>) "Maximum 'scrollback' value.\n\nThe maximum allowed i..." number vterm-min-window-width #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f40001536e1>) "Minimum window width." vterm-kill-buffer-on-exit #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f4000153e5d>) "If not nil vterm buffers are killed when the attac..." boolean defvaralias vterm-clear-scrollback vterm-clear-scrollback-when-clearing (saved-value saved-variable-comment) put make-obsolete-variable "0.0.1" vterm-use-vterm-prompt vterm-use-vterm-prompt-detection-method #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1f4000153e91>) "If not nil `vterm-clear' clears both screen and sc..." vterm-keymap-exceptions ...] 10)
  command-execute(vterm record)
  helm-M-x-execute-command(vterm)
  helm-execute-selection-action-1()
  helm-execute-selection-action()
  helm-internal((((name . "Emacs Commands history") (candidates . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1a6a9320e91d6978>)) (keymap keymap (keymap (13 . helm-confirm-and-exit-minibuffer)) keymap (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (127 . delete-backward-char) (27 keymap (13 . helm-cr-empty-string)) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (2 . backward-word) (6 . helm-next-page) (tab . helm-execute-persistent-action) (33554448 . helm-previous-source) (33554446 . helm-next-source) (33554438 . helm-previous-page) (remap keymap (previous-line . helm-previous-line) (next-line . helm-next-line)) (insert-state keymap (11 . previous-line) (10 . next-line) "Auxiliary keymap for Insert state") (33554443 . helm-previous-source) (33554442 . helm-next-source) (26 . helm-select-action) (21 . helm-delete-minibuffer-contents) (18 . evil-paste-from-register) (1 . move-beginning-of-line) (escape . abort-recursive-edit) (f13 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 12)) (f12 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 11)) (f11 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 10)) (f10 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 9)) (f9 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 8)) (f8 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 7)) (f7 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 6)) (f6 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 5)) (f5 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 4)) (f4 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 3)) (f3 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 2)) (f2 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 1)) (menu-bar keymap (help-menu keymap ...)) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match . identity) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . "TAB: Describe this command (keeping se...") (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (match-dynamic . t)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (candidates . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x18fdbb135dccbf97>)) (keymap keymap (keymap (13 . helm-confirm-and-exit-minibuffer)) keymap (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (127 . delete-backward-char) (27 keymap (13 . helm-cr-empty-string)) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (2 . backward-word) (6 . helm-next-page) (tab . helm-execute-persistent-action) (33554448 . helm-previous-source) (33554446 . helm-next-source) (33554438 . helm-previous-page) (remap keymap (previous-line . helm-previous-line) (next-line . helm-next-line)) (insert-state keymap (11 . previous-line) (10 . next-line) "Auxiliary keymap for Insert state") (33554443 . helm-previous-source) (33554442 . helm-next-source) (26 . helm-select-action) (21 . helm-delete-minibuffer-contents) (18 . evil-paste-from-register) (1 . move-beginning-of-line) (escape . abort-recursive-edit) (f13 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 12)) (f12 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 11)) (f11 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 10)) (f10 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 9)) (f9 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 8)) (f8 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 7)) (f7 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 6)) (f6 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 5)) (f5 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 4)) (f4 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 3)) (f3 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 2)) (f2 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 1)) (menu-bar keymap (help-menu keymap ...)) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match . identity) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . "TAB: Describe this command (keeping se...") (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (match-dynamic . t))) nil "M-x " nil nil "*helm M-x*" nil nil helm-M-x-input-history)
  helm((((name . "Emacs Commands history") (candidates . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1a6a9320e91d6978>)) (keymap keymap (keymap (13 . helm-confirm-and-exit-minibuffer)) keymap (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (127 . delete-backward-char) (27 keymap (13 . helm-cr-empty-string)) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (2 . backward-word) (6 . helm-next-page) (tab . helm-execute-persistent-action) (33554448 . helm-previous-source) (33554446 . helm-next-source) (33554438 . helm-previous-page) (remap keymap (previous-line . helm-previous-line) (next-line . helm-next-line)) (insert-state keymap (11 . previous-line) (10 . next-line) "Auxiliary keymap for Insert state") (33554443 . helm-previous-source) (33554442 . helm-next-source) (26 . helm-select-action) (21 . helm-delete-minibuffer-contents) (18 . evil-paste-from-register) (1 . move-beginning-of-line) (escape . abort-recursive-edit) (f13 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 12)) (f12 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 11)) (f11 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 10)) (f10 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 9)) (f9 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 8)) (f8 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 7)) (f7 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 6)) (f6 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 5)) (f5 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 4)) (f4 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 3)) (f3 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 2)) (f2 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 1)) (menu-bar keymap (help-menu keymap ...)) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match . identity) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . "TAB: Describe this command (keeping se...") (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (match-dynamic . t)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (candidates . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x18fdbb135dccbf97>)) (keymap keymap (keymap (13 . helm-confirm-and-exit-minibuffer)) keymap (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (127 . delete-backward-char) (27 keymap (13 . helm-cr-empty-string)) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (2 . backward-word) (6 . helm-next-page) (tab . helm-execute-persistent-action) (33554448 . helm-previous-source) (33554446 . helm-next-source) (33554438 . helm-previous-page) (remap keymap (previous-line . helm-previous-line) (next-line . helm-next-line)) (insert-state keymap (11 . previous-line) (10 . next-line) "Auxiliary keymap for Insert state") (33554443 . helm-previous-source) (33554442 . helm-next-source) (26 . helm-select-action) (21 . helm-delete-minibuffer-contents) (18 . evil-paste-from-register) (1 . move-beginning-of-line) (escape . abort-recursive-edit) (f13 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 12)) (f12 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 11)) (f11 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 10)) (f10 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 9)) (f9 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 8)) (f8 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 7)) (f7 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 6)) (f6 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 5)) (f5 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 4)) (f4 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 3)) (f3 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 2)) (f2 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 1)) (menu-bar keymap (help-menu keymap ...)) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match . identity) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . "TAB: Describe this command (keeping se...") (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (match-dynamic . t))) nil "M-x " nil nil "*helm M-x*" nil nil helm-M-x-input-history)
  helm(:sources (((name . "Emacs Commands history") (candidates . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1a6a9320e91d6978>)) (keymap keymap (keymap (13 . helm-confirm-and-exit-minibuffer)) keymap (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (127 . delete-backward-char) (27 keymap (13 . helm-cr-empty-string)) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (2 . backward-word) (6 . helm-next-page) (tab . helm-execute-persistent-action) (33554448 . helm-previous-source) (33554446 . helm-next-source) (33554438 . helm-previous-page) (remap keymap (previous-line . helm-previous-line) (next-line . helm-next-line)) (insert-state keymap (11 . previous-line) (10 . next-line) "Auxiliary keymap for Insert state") (33554443 . helm-previous-source) (33554442 . helm-next-source) (26 . helm-select-action) (21 . helm-delete-minibuffer-contents) (18 . evil-paste-from-register) (1 . move-beginning-of-line) (escape . abort-recursive-edit) (f13 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 12)) (f12 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 11)) (f11 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 10)) (f10 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 9)) (f9 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 8)) (f8 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 7)) (f7 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 6)) (f6 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 5)) (f5 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 4)) (f4 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 3)) (f3 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 2)) (f2 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 1)) (menu-bar keymap (help-menu keymap ...)) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match . identity) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . "TAB: Describe this command (keeping se...") (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (match-dynamic . t)) ((name . "Emacs Commands") (candidates . #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x18fdbb135dccbf97>)) (keymap keymap (keymap (13 . helm-confirm-and-exit-minibuffer)) keymap (21 . helm-M-x-universal-argument) keymap (127 . delete-backward-char) (27 keymap (13 . helm-cr-empty-string)) (C-return . helm-cr-empty-string) keymap (2 . backward-word) (6 . helm-next-page) (tab . helm-execute-persistent-action) (33554448 . helm-previous-source) (33554446 . helm-next-source) (33554438 . helm-previous-page) (remap keymap (previous-line . helm-previous-line) (next-line . helm-next-line)) (insert-state keymap (11 . previous-line) (10 . next-line) "Auxiliary keymap for Insert state") (33554443 . helm-previous-source) (33554442 . helm-next-source) (26 . helm-select-action) (21 . helm-delete-minibuffer-contents) (18 . evil-paste-from-register) (1 . move-beginning-of-line) (escape . abort-recursive-edit) (f13 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 12)) (f12 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 11)) (f11 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 10)) (f10 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 9)) (f9 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 8)) (f8 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 7)) (f7 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 6)) (f6 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 5)) (f5 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 4)) (f4 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 3)) (f3 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 2)) (f2 lambda nil (interactive) (helm-select-nth-action 1)) (menu-bar keymap (help-menu keymap ...)) ...) (action . helm-type-command-actions) (persistent-action . helm-M-x-persistent-action) (persistent-help . "Describe this command") (help-message . helm-M-x-help-message) (requires-pattern . 0) (filtered-candidate-transformer helm-M-x-transformer-no-sort helm-fuzzy-highlight-matches) (volatile . t) (match . identity) (redisplay . identity) (nomark . t) (coerce . helm-symbolify) (header-line . "TAB: Describe this command (keeping se...") (must-match . t) (group . helm-command) (match-dynamic . t))) :prompt "M-x " :buffer "*helm M-x*" :history helm-M-x-input-history)
  helm-M-x-read-extended-command([evil-collection-magit-toggle-text-minor-mode magit-section-show-headings org-element-paragraph-separate calendar-forward-week tramp-sudoedit-file-name-handler tramp-completion-handle-file-name-all-completions term-do-line-wrapping lsp-watch-kind\? org-indent-drawer Reduce\ To:\ to\ Cc: traverse c-electric-lt-gt helm-completing-read-inbuffer-default-handler url-cookie-p term-handle-exit vterm-keymap-exceptions flycheck-mode-line-prefix cl-struct-flycheck-syntax-check-tags helm-ff-query-replace-fnames-history-to racket-insert-closing-bracket org-table--descriptor-line edebug-mode-on-hook message-expand-name-databases info--manual-names 0 tree-widget-button-keymap flycheck-coffee-coffeelint-executable magit-list-modified-modules :where which-key--stop-timer browse-url-gnome-moz-arguments flycheck-pug-executable tramp-sudoedit-handle-set-file-acl org-table-get-range helm-highlight-bookmark WatchKind lsp:set-rename-params-uri\? org-agenda-regexp-filter-preset browse-url-generic-args org-agenda-menu-show-matcher lsp:set-server-capabilities-document-symbol-provider\? helm-grep-save-results-1 dired-do-chmod server--on-display-p undo-fu-session-mode-turn-on check-declare Info-breadcrumbs :org-comment tramp-handle-make-auto-save-file-name flycheck-puppet-lint-disabled-arg-name ...])
  helm-M-x(nil)
  funcall-interactively(helm-M-x nil)
  command-execute(helm-M-x)
```

EDIT: Here's a minimal reproducible example.  I do not know how to fix it without removing the whole section from the bindings.

`config.el`:

```
;;; .doom.d/config.el -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(load! "bindings/+bindings")
```

`+bindings.el`:

```
;;; ~/.doom.d/+bindings.el -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;;; config/default/+bindings.el -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(map! :leader
      (:desc "help" :prefix "h"
        :n "h" help-map
        )
      )
```

Comment: Too much going on. Try running Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) and loading only a minimal set of code to repro the problem. E.g., do you see the problem if you don't load Helm (you just use vanilla `M-x`)? Don't try to debug (or ask people here) to debug a problem involving a giant sack of code. Please try to narrow things down.

Comment: @Drew I have included a stacktrace. I have tried `emacs -Q`, but since `vterm` is not loaded then, I have no way of knowing if the problem persists then or not. I do not know how to narrow the problem down.